# Why does ((count++)) return 1 exit code first time run

Tags: bash

I have no idea why the indicated line below is returning 1 while the subsequent executions of `((count++))` are returning 0.

```
[me@server ~]$ count=0
[me@server ~]$ echo $?
0
[me@server ~]$ count++
-bash: count++: command not found
[me@server ~]$ (count++)
-bash: count++: command not found
[me@server ~]$ ((count++))
[me@server ~]$ echo $?
1 <------THIS WHY IS IT 1 AND NOT 0??
[me@server ~]$ ((count++))
[me@server ~]$ echo $?
0
[me@server ~]$ ((count++))
[me@server ~]$ echo $?
0
[me@server ~]$ echo $count
3
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See the excerpt from the `help let` page,

> If the last ARG evaluates to 0, let returns 1; 0 is returned
> otherwise.

Since the operation is post-increment, `((count++))`, for the very first time `0` is retained, hence returning `1`

Notice, the same does not happen for pre-increment `((++count))`, since the value is set to `1`, on the first iteration itself.

```bash
$ count=0
$ ((++count))
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: Just lost two hours on this.. Argh!! I'll stick to `count=$((count+1))`